# Compatible 'to' or 'with' or both?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do you use in combination with *compatible*? *With* or *to*, or are both possible? If both are possible, when do you use which option? What is the difference?

Example:

> This software is compatible *to/with* this operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Compatible to** or **compatible with**

Short answer: **with**.

Slightly longer answer: You can find this information in virtually any dictionary.

- **compatible** adj. (often **compatible with**) ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/compatible )
- "This software may not be compatible **with** older operating systems" (the emphasis is present in the original at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compatible )
- **compatible with** ( https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/compatible )
- **compatible with** ( https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/compatible )

Comment: Funny, that I nearly used the same example as the cambridge dictionary.